# How to ignore a part of a string on a column value

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I write this sql for joining two tables. Is there some regex for ignoring all emails which end with `@info.com`. I do not want to print them after executing the query.

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
RIGHT OUTER JOIN users_map
ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
      users_map.service_user_id = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly do string operation using like.

e.g.

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
RIGHT OUTER JOIN users_map
ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
    users_map.service_user_id = 0 AND
    user_data.alternative_mail NOT LIKE '%@info.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can do it with REPLACE function :

```
SELECT replace(user_data.alternative_mail,'@info.com','')
FROM user_data
RIGHT OUTER JOIN users_map
ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
      users_map.service_user_id = 0
```

Or if you want to filter them from the results, the you should use like :

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
RIGHT OUTER JOIN users_map
ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
      users_map.service_user_id = 0 AND
      user_data.alternative_mail NOT LIKE '%@info.com'
```